# how to build complete certificate name, include serial number using openssl's index.txt

Tags: lua, openssl, pattern-matching

**Problem Description:**

I need to build a regular expression / pattern to find a value that can either be decimal or hex

**Background Information:**

I am trying to build a lua function that will lookup a cert in index.txt and return the serial number.  Ultimately, I need to be able to take the full cert name and run the following command:

> openssl x509 -noout -in
>   /etc/ssl/cert/myusername.6A756C65654063616E2E77746274732E6E6574.8F.crt
>   -dates

I have the logic to build the file name, all the way up to the serial number... which in the above example, is 8F.

Here's what the index.txt file looks like:

```
R   140320154649Z   150325040807Z   8E  unknown /CN=test@gmail.com/emailAddress=test@gmail.com
V   160324050821Z       8F  unknown /CN=test@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test@yahoo.com
V   160324051723Z       90  unknown /CN=test2@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test2@yahoo.com
```

The serial number is field 4 in the first record, and field 3 in the rest of the records. 
According to the documentation https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html, serial number can either be hex or decimal.
I'm not quite sure yet how / who determines whether it's hex or decimal (i'm modifying someone else's code that uses openssl)... but I'm wondering if there's a way to check for both. I'll only be checking the value for records that are not Revoked ...aka. ones that do not have "R" in the first column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua unfortunately does not support grouping of patterns, so that you could make the pattern for the second timestamp optional. What you could do is check for the two-timestamp pattern first, and if no match was found (which means that `match` returns `nil`), repeat for the one-timestamp pattern:

```
sn = string.match(line, "^%a%s+%d+Z%s+%d+Z%s+(%x+)")
if not sn then
    sn = string.match(line, "^%a%s+%d+Z%s+(%x+)")
end
```

Note that you could do this all in one line if you're eager:

```
sn = string.match(line, "^%a%s+%d+Z%s+%d+Z%s+(%x+)") or string.match(line, "^%a%s+%d+Z%s+(%x+)")
```

Each set of parentheses captures what is matched inside and adds a return value. For more information on patterns in Lua, see the [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1).

Answer (score 1):

```
local cert = {
   'R   140320154649Z   150325040807Z    8E  unknown /CN=test@gmail.com/emailAddress=test@gmail.com',
   'V   160324050821Z       8F  unknown /CN=test@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test@yahoo.com',
   'V   160324051723Z       90  unknown /CN=test2@yahoo.com/emailAddress=test2@yahoo.com'
}

-- for Lua 5.1
for _, crt in ipairs(cert) do
   local n3, n4 = crt:match'^%S+%s+%S+%s+(%S+)%s+(%S+)'
   local serial  = n3:match'^%x+$' or n4:match'^%x+$'
   print(serial)
end

-- for Lua 5.2
for _, crt in ipairs(cert) do
   local serial = crt:match'^%S+%s+%S+.-%f[%S](%x+)%f[%s]'
   print(serial)
end
```

Comment: Egor, can you explain the _, syntax a little?  Thank you!

Comment: @dot - The variable consisting of only an underscore "_" is commonly used as a placeholder when you want to ignore the variable.

Comment: egor, thank you very much for the help.  I think i'm going to use m.buettner's answer only because I'm not going to use the table.  I'm going to extract the one line that I need.  but thanks again. your answer was very useful and educationa